# Determine what param to use in Select statement in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that returns a common query, I need to call it in several functions but some functions may call it through Period Id or others through Header Id, so far I would like to know how can I determine what param to use in order to retrive data properly, I have something like this implemented.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetTFDRecordInfo
    @PeriodId int = null,
    @HeaderId int  = null
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        -- I have a lot more fields and joins here, that's why I need to get the statement in a single call through either period id or header id 
        *   
        From NT_CSRTNVPeriodInfo t

        -- how can I make possible something like shown above, can I use a "Case When"?
        Where (             
                /*
                if @PeriodId is null 
                    Where t.HeaderId = @HeaderId

                if @HeaderId is null
                    Where t.PeriodId = @PeriodId
                */
            )    
END
GO

-- swtich between params
Exec NT_CSRTNVPeriodInfo null, 2654
Exec NT_CSRTNVPeriodInfo 196, null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetTFDRecordInfo
    @PeriodId int = null,
    @HeaderId int  = null
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        -- I have a lot more fields and joins here, that's why I need to get the statement in a single call through either period id or header id 
        *   
        From NT_CSRTNVPeriodInfo t

        -- how can I make possible something like shown above, can I use a "Case When"?
        Where ((@PeriodId IS NULL) or (t.PeriodId = @PeriodId))
        And   ((@HeaderId IS NULL) or (t.HeaderId = @HeaderId))
END
GO
```

You have to use conditional OR to check NULLs, if param is set, the second condition is checked, if not, the procedure will consider always true the statement and go to the next.

Comment: I'm sorry @marc_s, I've deleted all with copy/paste.

Comment: it looks cool, I did something a little like it but did not work, let me test it bro